# attributeerror 'module' object has no attribute 'openfile'

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the error that occurred using Python. I'm trying to use the module detektspikes.py freely distributed by klustakwik team.

I'm having trouble with errors that occurred when run.

Error log:

```
Exiting directory C:\Users\user\Downloads\klusta-team-spikedetekt-82bcf06\klusta
-team-spikedetekt-82bcf06\scripts_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\klusta-team-spikedetekt-82bcf06\klusta-team-spik
edetekt-82bcf06\scripts\detektspikes.py", line 82, in <module>
spike_detection_job(raw_data_files, probe_file, output_dir, output_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spikedetekt\core.py", line 86, in 
spike_de
tection_job
probe, max_spikes)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spikedetekt\core.py", line 115, in 
spike_d
etection_from_raw_data
h5s[n] = tables.openFile(filename, 'w')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openFile'
```

I guess the problem is on the core.py

Core.py :

```
 Filter, detect, extract from raw data.
"""
### Detect spikes. For each detected spike, send it to spike writer, which
### writes it to a spk file. List of times is small (memorywise) so we just
### store the list and write it later.

np.savetxt("dat_channels.txt", Channels_dat, fmt="%i")

# Create HDF5 files
h5s = {}
h5s_filenames = {}
for n in ['main', 'waves']:
    filename = basename+'.'+n+'.h5'
    h5s[n] = tables.openFile(filename, 'w')
    h5s_filenames[n] = filename
for n in ['raw', 'high', 'low']:
    if Parameters['RECORD_'+n.upper()]:
        filename = basename+'.'+n+'.h5'
        h5s[n] = tables.openFile(filename, 'w')
        h5s_filenames[n] = filename
main_h5 = h5s['main']
# Shanks groups
shanks_group = {}
shank_group = {}
shank_table = {}
for k in ['main', 'waves']:
    h5 = h5s[k]
    shanks_group[k] = h5.createGroup('/', 'shanks')
    for i in probe.shanks_set:
```

I would pleased to be kindly helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that that code is for a very old version of Python and trying to access a no longer existing method of `tables`. See here: http://www.pytables.org/MIGRATING_TO_3.x.html

If you want to run the script you'd have to run it in an old version of Python like 2.3, or update the lines that use `openFile` to use `open_file` instead. Though there may be other incompatibilities that I'm not aware of.

Comment: thanks! I solved it by editing the lines to open_file.